# Using Django F expressions with many-to-many fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to write a Django query which filters on if a foreign key field A is contained in a collection B. Collection B is a many-to-many field on the model, and so I'm using [F-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to try and compare the two. The actual query is with more complex model relations and using [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)s and [`OuterRef`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef)s, but since `OuterRef` is a special type of `F` expression for use with the `Subquery` object, any guidance on how to use `F`-expressions with many-to-many fields would be really helpful. Here are the simplified models we're working with:

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Review(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor)
    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(Instructor)
```

Where `instructor` is not necessarily in `instructors`

The query we would like to do:

```
Review.objects.filter(instructor__in=F('instructors'))
```

After lots of searching on Google and StackOverflow, I couldn't find any examples of F expressions being used with many-to-many fields. Are they not compatible? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work

```
Review.objects.filter(instructors=F('instructor'))
```

Filtering on "instructors" creates a join on the instructor table, then we filter the join where the "instructor" foreign key equals the joined entry from the instructor table. Using the "id" column probably makes it a little clearer

```
Review.objects.filter(instructors__id=F('instructor_id'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The issue is, `instructors` needs to be inside of an `OuterRef` for the `Subquery`, and so can't be on the left-hand-side of a filter / lookup expression as far as I know.

Comment: @dbh937 can you give an example of the query you are using? It's hard to debug without it